# Java-Stream - How Collecor groupingBy() to split a Map into multiple Submaps

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

I have the following `Student` object:

```
public class Student {
    private String gradeAndClass;
    private String gender;
    private String name;

    // getters, constructor, etc.
}
```

<sup>In the original code, properties **gradeAndClass** and **gender** are *enums*, but for the purpose of simplicity let's consider them to be strings.</sup>

I have a map `Map<String,Student>`, where *key* is a unique string and *value* is a `Student` object.

I need this map to split into a bunch of maps `Map<String,Student>`, so the result should be a *list of submaps* `List<Map<String,Student>>`.

Let's consider the following example:

```
Map<String, Student> data = new HashMap<>();

data.put("key1", new Student("class_1", "Boy", "Jo"));
data.put("key2", new Student("class_2", "Girl", "Alice"));
data.put("key3", new Student("class_1", "Girl", "Amy"));
data.put("key4", new Student("class_2", "Girl", "May"));
data.put("key5", new Student("class_1", "Boy", "Oscar"));
data.put("key6", new Student("class_2", "Boy", "Jimmy"));
data.put("key7", new Student("illegal class name", "Boy", "err1"));
data.put("key8", new Student("class_2", "not supported", "err2"));
```

Is there an easy way to split the `Map` first by `gradeAndClass` then by `gender`, so that the result would be a list containing the following *submaps*:

- *Submap 1:*

```
"key1", ["class_1", "Boy", "Jo"]
"key5", ["class_1", "Boy", "Oscar"]
```

- *Submap 2:*

```
"key3", ["class_1", "Girl", "Amy"]
```

- *Submap 3:*

```
"key6", ["class_2", "Boy", "Jimmy"]
```

- *Submap 4:*

```
"key2", ["class_2", "Girl", "Alice"]
"key4", ["class_2", "Girl", "May"]
```

Also, I'd like to aggregate the illegal inputs to a separate map:

- *Submap 5:*

```
"key7", ["illegal class name", "boy", "err1"]
"key8", ["class_2", "not supported", "err2"]
```

I tried to filter data related to each submap separately (*making use of the fact* `gradeAndClass` *and* `gender` *in the original code are well-defined enums*), but it is very inefficient.

Basically, I've hard-coded all the condition checks and had to filter and regroup by each `gradeAndClass` and `gender`. I also had to reiterate each entry to get the illegal entries in order to put them to a separate *"error map"*.

Sorry, I am very new to streams, so I know my solution is definitely not scalable, and thus I am looking for suggestion. Would it be possible to use stream `groupingBy()` to do all these?

*Here's the code I've used to generate a separate submap:*

```
Map<String, Student> submap = data.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> "class_1".equals(entry.getValue()) &&
                     (other conditions))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue
    ));
```

Comment: Oops, thanks for catching it. I just corrected submap #5. 

The input is just a Map <String, Student>, the key is defined by caller (due to some business restriction), so goal is to group the students by class/gender/etc. and for each group it will be calling dedicated handler. Instead of simply filtering the illegal inputs, we also want to return all the failed instances to the caller.

Comment: So my goal is to get all the submaps, which use the same structure as the input. I am just trying to partition my input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248049/discussion-between-alexander-ivanchenko-and-guiqin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To group students by *grade* and by *gender*, we need an object combining those two properties.

For that, we can use Java 16 [`record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html), or a `class` for earlier JDK versions (alternatively there are few quick and dirty options like `List<Object>`, or concatenated `String` but it doesn't byes you anything, so I would not advise going this route).

```
record Key(String gradeAndClass, String gender) {}
```

As the first step, we need to create an *auxiliary map* which associates each *Key* (corresponding to a particular grade & gender) with a *list of entries* of the *source-map* (containing a string key and a student object). And that can be done using collector `groupingBy()`.

Then we need to transform each *list* in the *auxiliary map* into a `Map<String,Student>` and collect the result into a list.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
List<Map<String, Student>> result = data.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        entry -> new Key(entry.getValue().getGradeAndClass(),
                         entry.getValue().getGender())
    ))
    .values().stream()
    .map(list -> list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue
        ))
    ).toList(); // or .collect(Collectors.toList()) for JDK versions earlier than 16
```

In order to group entries containing `Student` object with incorrect value of grade or unspecified gender, you can implement a utility method that would, containing conditional logic for spotting such erroneous objects and returning a special instance of a `Key` (i.e. instantiated once and defined as `static final` field). If an object is valid an "normal" `Key` should be returned.

When you have this method implemented just replace the *classifier* function of `groupingBy()` with a *method reference* which makes use of it.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and for the example! I just tried and it works! I will look into how to get the error map. Thank you!!

Comment: @guiqin Added a comment in regard to the handling of erroneous `Student` objects (see at the very end of the answer).

Comment: This post is helpful as I have exactly the same use case! 

But what if I want the result to be a nested map? E.g., I want to group the data map by gender, but I need to output it as nested map where the gender will be the key of the nested map, and the sub-map will be the value. How can I achieve it?

Comment: @GreenHo Hi, that doable, as well. You can use *nested collectors* to generate a nested map (the first collector would split the data-set based on the first property, and the downstream collector would deal with the second property). How it would look like depends on details of your problem. Comments are not well-suitable for answering questions.

Comment: @GreenHo If you're stuck with implementing it, I advise you to **open a question** and describe your problem carefully (don't forget to provide the **code attempt**, if you experience difficulties with stream-based solution, then at least try to solve it using loops, it always brings value to a question and folks are more eager to answer it, then "give-me-code" questions). Also, fill free to notify me by posting a comment with a link.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Thanks! I will try nested collectors as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve that using Java 8 Streams groupingBy method. Following is the sample code

```
Map<String, List<Map.Entry<String, Student>>> filters = data.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.getValue().getGradeAndClass()));
```

Output is

```
illegal class name=[key7=Student@2d98a335], 
class_2=[key2=Student@16b98e56, key6=Student@7ef20235, key4=Student@27d6c5e0, key8=Student@4f3f5b24]
class_1=[key1=Student@15aeb7ab, key5=Student@7b23ec81, key3=Student@6acbcfc0]}
```